# TCP flow control on Indy TCP Server

Tags: windows, delphi, indy

The Indy TIdTCPServer component has an OnExecute event where you can process incoming data. My application involves streaming data that is processed before going to a printer, so I'm dependent on the output device being ready. What I want to do is let the TCP flow control manage the input stream in the event of the output stream being busy.

What I don't know is how to best handle this situation. The Indy documentation is a little light on usage examples, any guidance appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to deal with TCP/IP flow control manually.  Simply do not read any new input data in your OnExecute code if the the device is not ready, that is all you have to do.  The data will sit in the socket's receive buffer until Indy reads it into its own buffer, where it will then sit unil you read it ino your own code.  If the socket's receive buffer fills up, TCP/IP will automatically notify the other party to stop sending data until the buffer frees up some space.

Comment: The `OnExecute` event is fired in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the connection, regardless of the data flow. When the event exits, it is immediately fired again. It is the responsibility of the code inside of the event to wait for data as needed. All read operations go to Indy's own `InputBuffer`. Indy goes to the socket receive buffer only when it needs new data to fill the `InputBuffer` to satisfy a read.

Answer (score 0):

not sure to what grade you already develped your own code. 
If your are still a beginner  you  might find the demo samples from http://sourceforge.net/projects/indy10clieservr/   helpful as a starting point.